# Is it possible to buy NFTs on opensea using web3py

Tags: web3.py

Is it possible to buy NFTs on opensea using web3py, if so is there any good resources ? I would imagine it would be interacting with opensea's smart contract right ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can interact with their smart contract directly and replicate their transactions using web3.

But you can also use their REST [API](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/api-overview) as an SDK, instead of directly working with their smart contracts.

Comment: I dont seem to see any documentation on the REST API, for the most part its mostly about retrieving data on opensea, are you referring to their sdk here ? 

https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js